# Call/use a datagridview from another class

Tags: c#, class, datagridview

I have a class which contains a method (function) which should modify the dataGridView from the Form. How can I call the dataGridView from the Form inside that class?

I tried looking for "DataGridView" type of variable to pass as a parameter but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
internal class DataGridViewUpdater
{
    internal void UpdateDataGridView(DataGridView dv)
    {
        // Grid view update code here    
    }
}
```

In your Form Load, you can do something like this:

```
 DataGridViewUpdater dvu = new DataGridViewUpdater();
        dvu.UpdateDataGridView(dataGridView1);
```

Comment: If you are trying to modify data in DataGridView then better apporach would be to use Collection of an entity. You can pass Collection instance from your Form class to any class and update the collection and give it back to Form class. Form class will update datasource of DataGridView.

Comment: I am going to use the DataGridView to add/remove/read rows from it.